# Generate email from cell value with indents, and keep default signature format

Tags: excel, vba

I've a macro to send an e-mail through Outlook.

The body is from a cell value with indents. Since the value will change depending on the usage, I need to reference that cell.

Using `.HTMLbody`
I lose indents which are constructed with CHAR(10).
I keep the default HTML signature.

Using `.BODY`
Indents are displayed.
The default signature is not constructed as HTML and I lose the images.

My code:

```vb
sig = .HTMLBody
body = xlSht.Range("B4").Value
    .To = xlSht.Range("B2").Value
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = xlSht.Range("B1").Value
    .body = body & sig
    .Display
```

Comment: Maybe `body = Replace(body, vbLf, "<br>")` and then use HTMLBody

Comment: I faced this issue before, and fixed it by change `BodyFormat` of MailItem varirable to **olFormatHTML**
,kindly adapt to you code `Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
objNewEmail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML`

Comment: thank you man. I have actually done a similar thing while waiting for experts to step in. I included a helper text in the cell and used

.HTMLBODY = Replace(body,"helper","<br>")

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I included a helper text in the cell and used

```
.HTMLBODY = Replace(body,"helper","<br>")
```